# Replace only xhtml files

Tags: command-line, scripts, rsync

With this command I copy the different files and replace them in the destination.

```
rsync -av --existing web/src/main/webapp/com/* web/target/project/com/
```

How do I replace only files with `.xhtml` extension?

Answer (score 0):

In your command `*` will be be expanded to any kind of files in "src" directory meaning all of them (even directories), with `*.xhtml` you can only target files with the `.xhtml` extensions.

```
rsync -av --existing web/src/main/webapp/com/*.xhtml web/target/project/com/
```

With this command only files with `xhtml` extension in  `web/target/project/com/` going to be updated.

Comment: I got error: `rsync: link_stat "/home/douglas/workspace/project/trunk/web/src/main/webapp/com/*.xhtml" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Make sure you have files with `xhtml` extension in your source directory. `ls /home/douglas/workspace/project/trunk/web/src/main/webapp/c‌​om/*.xhtml`